# Autofac performance with method RegisterSingleComponent and UpdateInitialisedAdapters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac, mvcsitemapprovider

I have web application ASP.NET MVC for IoC I use **Autofac**
Using Autofac I see problem with starting App 20 - 21 sec. For check I used JetBrains dotTrace, and got this picture

[image: Autofac performance]

How I can fix this problem? Also in project I using **MvcSiteMapProvider**

```
 public class IocCommon
{
    private static IContainer _container;

    private static Assembly[] _sgnAssemblies;

    public static Assembly[] SgnAssemblies
    {
        get
        {
            return _sgnAssemblies ?? (_sgnAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(item => item.FullName.Contains("SGN") && !item.FullName.Contains("Web")&& !item.FullName.Contains("Controls")).ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

       builder.RegisterControllers(SgnAssemblies);
        builder.Register(c => new CoreContext()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        var entities = GetEntityList();

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var regType = GetGenericType(typeof(BaseRepository<>), entity);
            var asType = GetGenericType(typeof(IRepository<>), entity);

            builder.RegisterType(regType).As(asType);
        }

        var services = GetSeriveTypes().Where(item => item.Key != typeof(IDictionaryService<>));

        foreach (var service in services)
        {
            builder.RegisterType(service.Value).As(service.Key);
        }

        var dictonaryEntity = entities.Where(item => item.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IDiconary)));

        foreach (var entity in dictonaryEntity)
        {
            var regType = GetGenericType(typeof(DictionaryService<>), entity);
            var asType = GetGenericType(typeof(IDictionaryService<>), entity);

            builder.RegisterType(regType).As(asType);
        }

        // Register modules
        builder.RegisterModule(new MvcSiteMapProviderModule(SgnAssemblies.ToList())); // Required
        builder.RegisterModule(new MvcModule()); // Required by MVC. Typically already part of your setup (double check the contents of the module).

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()).PreserveExistingDefaults();

        // Override default dependency resolver to use Autofac
        _container = builder.Build();
        MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Loader = _container.Resolve<ISiteMapLoader>();
        var validator = _container.Resolve<ISiteMapXmlValidator>();
        validator.ValidateXml(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Mvc.sitemap"));

        // Register the Sitemaps routes for search engines (optional)
        XmlSiteMapController.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(_container));
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        _container.Dispose();
    }

    public static T GetObject<T>()
    {
        return _container.Resolve<T>();
    }

    public static T GetObject<T>(params Parameter[] parameters)
    {
        return _container.Resolve<T>(parameters);
    }


    public static List<Type> GetEntityList()
    {
        var entityList = new List<Type>();

        foreach (var assembly in SgnAssemblies)
        {
            var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(item => item.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEntity)));
            entityList.AddRange(types);
        }

        return entityList;
    }

    public static Dictionary<Type, Type> GetSeriveTypes()
    {
        var dic = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

        foreach (var assembly in SgnAssemblies)
        {               
            var serviceInterfaces = assembly.GetTypes().Where(item => item.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IDependency)) && item.IsInterface);

            foreach (var serviceInterface in serviceInterfaces)
            {
                var serviceClasses = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(item => item.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.Name == serviceInterface.Name));
                dic.Add(serviceInterface, serviceClasses);
            }
        }

        return dic;
    }

    public static Type GetGenericType(Type genericType, Type elemenType)
    {
        return genericType.MakeGenericType(elemenType);
    }
}
```

Module map provider

```
public class MvcSiteMapProviderModule
        : global::Autofac.Module
    {
        private List<Assembly> sgnAssemblies;

        public MvcSiteMapProviderModule(List<Assembly> sgnAssemblies)
        {
            this.sgnAssemblies = sgnAssemblies;
        }

        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            bool enableLocalization = true;
            string absoluteFileName = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Mvc.sitemap");
            TimeSpan absoluteCacheExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            bool visibilityAffectsDescendants = true;
            bool useTitleIfDescriptionNotProvided = true;


            bool securityTrimmingEnabled = false;
            string[] includeAssembliesForScan = sgnAssemblies.Select(item => item.FullName).ToArray();

            var siteMapProviderAssembly = typeof(SiteMaps).Assembly;

            sgnAssemblies.Add(siteMapProviderAssembly);
            //var allAssemblies = new Assembly[] { currentAssembly, siteMapProviderAssembly };
            var allAssemblies = sgnAssemblies.ToArray();
            var excludeTypes = new Type[] {
// Use this array to add types you wish to explicitly exclude from convention-based  
// auto-registration. By default all types that either match I[TypeName] = [TypeName] or 
// I[TypeName] = [TypeName]Adapter will be automatically wired up as long as they don't 
// have the [ExcludeFromAutoRegistrationAttribute].
//
// If you want to override a type that follows the convention, you should add the name 
// of either the implementation name or the interface that it inherits to this list and 
// add your manual registration code below. This will prevent duplicate registrations 
// of the types from occurring. 

// Example:
// typeof(SiteMap),
// typeof(SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy)
            };
            var multipleImplementationTypes = new[] {
                typeof(ISiteMapNodeUrlResolver),
                typeof(ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider),
                typeof(IDynamicNodeProvider)
            };

// Matching type name (I[TypeName] = [TypeName]) or matching type name + suffix Adapter (I[TypeName] = [TypeName]Adapter)
// and not decorated with the [ExcludeFromAutoRegistrationAttribute].
            CommonConventions.RegisterDefaultConventions(
                (interfaceType, implementationType) => builder.RegisterType(implementationType).As(interfaceType).SingleInstance(),
                new[] { siteMapProviderAssembly },
                allAssemblies,
                excludeTypes,
                string.Empty);

// Multiple implementations of strategy based extension points (and not decorated with [ExcludeFromAutoRegistrationAttribute]).
            CommonConventions.RegisterAllImplementationsOfInterface(
                (interfaceType, implementationType) => builder.RegisterType(implementationType).As(interfaceType).SingleInstance(),
                multipleImplementationTypes,
                allAssemblies,
                excludeTypes,
                string.Empty);

// Registration of internal controllers
            CommonConventions.RegisterAllImplementationsOfInterface(
                (interfaceType, implementationType) => builder.RegisterType(implementationType).As(interfaceType).AsSelf().InstancePerDependency(),
                new[] { typeof(IController) },
                new[] { siteMapProviderAssembly },
                new Type[0],
                string.Empty);

// Visibility Providers
            builder.RegisterType<SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy>()
                .As<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy>()
                .WithParameter("defaultProviderName", "MvcSiteMapProvider.FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider");

// Pass in the global controllerBuilder reference
            builder.RegisterInstance(ControllerBuilder.Current)
                   .As<ControllerBuilder>();

            builder.RegisterType<ControllerTypeResolverFactory>()
                .As<IControllerTypeResolverFactory>()
                .WithParameter("areaNamespacesToIgnore", new string[0]);

// Configure Security
            builder.RegisterType<AuthorizeAttributeAclModule>()
                .Named<IAclModule>("authorizeAttributeAclModule");
            builder.RegisterType<XmlRolesAclModule>()
                .Named<IAclModule>("xmlRolesAclModule");
            builder.RegisterType<CompositeAclModule>()
                .As<IAclModule>()
                .WithParameter(
                    (p, c) => p.Name == "aclModules",
                    (p, c) => new[]
                        {
                            c.ResolveNamed<IAclModule>("authorizeAttributeAclModule"),
                            c.ResolveNamed<IAclModule>("xmlRolesAclModule")
                        });

            builder.RegisterInstance(System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default)
                   .As<System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache>();

            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(RuntimeCacheProvider<>))
                .As(typeof(ICacheProvider<>));

            builder.RegisterType<RuntimeFileCacheDependency>()
                .Named<ICacheDependency>("cacheDependency")
                .WithParameter("fileName", absoluteFileName);

            builder.RegisterType<CacheDetails>()
                .Named<ICacheDetails>("cacheDetails")
                .WithParameter("absoluteCacheExpiration", absoluteCacheExpiration)
                .WithParameter("slidingCacheExpiration", TimeSpan.MinValue)
                .WithParameter(
                    (p, c) => p.Name == "cacheDependency",
                    (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<ICacheDependency>("cacheDependency"));

// Configure the visitors
            builder.RegisterType<UrlResolvingSiteMapNodeVisitor>()
                   .As<ISiteMapNodeVisitor>();

// Prepare for our node providers
            builder.RegisterType<FileXmlSource>()
                .Named<IXmlSource>("xmlSource")
                .WithParameter("fileName", absoluteFileName);

            builder.RegisterType<ReservedAttributeNameProvider>()
                .As<IReservedAttributeNameProvider>()
                .WithParameter("attributesToIgnore", new string[0]);


// Register the sitemap node providers
            builder.RegisterType<XmlSiteMapNodeProvider>()
                .Named<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("xmlSiteMapNodeProvider")
                .WithParameter("includeRootNode", true)
                .WithParameter("useNestedDynamicNodeRecursion", false)
                .WithParameter(
                    (p, c) => p.Name == "xmlSource",
                    (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IXmlSource>("xmlSource"));

            builder.RegisterType<ReflectionSiteMapNodeProvider>()
                .Named<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("reflectionSiteMapNodeProvider")
                .WithParameter("includeAssemblies", includeAssembliesForScan)
                .WithParameter("excludeAssemblies", new string[0]);

            builder.RegisterType<CompositeSiteMapNodeProvider>()
                .Named<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("siteMapNodeProvider")
                .WithParameter(
                    (p, c) => p.Name == "siteMapNodeProviders",
                    (p, c) => new[]
                        {
                            c.ResolveNamed<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("xmlSiteMapNodeProvider"),
                            c.ResolveNamed<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("reflectionSiteMapNodeProvider")
                        });

// Register the sitemap builders
            builder.RegisterType<SiteMapBuilder>()
                .Named<ISiteMapBuilder>("siteMapBuilder")
                .WithParameter(
                    (p, c) => p.Name == "siteMapNodeProvider",
                    (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("siteMapNodeProvider"));

// Configure the builder sets
            builder.RegisterType<SiteMapBuilderSet>()
                   .Named<ISiteMapBuilderSet>("builderSet")
                   .WithParameter("instanceName", "default")
                   .WithParameter("securityTrimmingEnabled", securityTrimmingEnabled)
                   .WithParameter("enableLocalization", enableLocalization)
                   .WithParameter("visibilityAffectsDescendants", visibilityAffectsDescendants)
                   .WithParameter("useTitleIfDescriptionNotProvided", useTitleIfDescriptionNotProvided)
                   .WithParameter(
                        (p, c) => p.Name == "siteMapBuilder",
                        (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<ISiteMapBuilder>("siteMapBuilder"))
                   .WithParameter(
                        (p, c) => p.Name == "cacheDetails",
                        (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<ICacheDetails>("cacheDetails"));

            builder.RegisterType<SiteMapBuilderSetStrategy>()
                .As<ISiteMapBuilderSetStrategy>()
                .WithParameter(
                    (p, c) => p.Name == "siteMapBuilderSets",
                    (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<ISiteMapBuilderSet>>("builderSet"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to show us your registration code that starts this call stack. Chances are the optimization will be in the registration code.

Comment: I add code and update post also added module of map provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()).PreserveExistingDefaults();
```

With that line, you are literally taking *every assembly in the entire AppDomain and registering every type in all of those assemblies* into Autofac.

It takes a lot of time to iterate through every type in every assembly in the entire AppDomain. :)

I'm guessing you're doing that because you don't want to follow the whole chain of dependencies in the MVC site map provider and register every dependent type.

[Luckily, Autofac has an answer for that in the `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource`.](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/registration-sources.html#any-concrete-type-not-already-registered-source)

Replace your giant assembly scanning line with this:

```
builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());
```

That will allow any type that isn't already explicitly registered with Autofac to act like it is registered. And it should run in a couple of *milliseconds* rather than *seconds*.

Comment: If that is the case, you can just remove the line altogether. The `MvcSiteMapProviderModule` already does convention-based building of the types it requires, there is no need to do it again.